# Referencing variables by using a vector containing multiple character strings

Tags: r, quantmod

I am using R to pull financial data from Yahoo with Quantmod's **getSymbols()** function. I use a character vector, Tickers, as the first argument in **getSymbols()** and the function then creates xts objects of each symbol passed from the **Tickers** vector. I then would like to merge the various xts objects into one object to perform further analysis on. Rather than typing out each new object's name, I would like to reference back to the original **Tickers** vector and use its contents (a vector of strings) to reference the newly created objects/variables.

So far I've fiddled around with various combinations of the below functions, but have had no luck:

- assign(Ticker, merge(Ticker))
- eval(parse(text = Ticker) --- This seems promising but only returns the *last* object in the Ticker vector. So close yet so far.
- get()
- as.name / as.symbol
- rlang::syms()

```
library(tidyverse)
library(quantmod)

# Symbol List
Tickers <- c("RY", "TD", "BNS", "BMO", "CM") 

# From To
StartDate <- as.Date("2001-01-01", format = "%Y-%m-%d")
EndDate <- Sys.Date()

# Symbol Lookup Function
SymLookup <- function(ticker, from){
  assign(ticker, getSymbols(ticker, from = StartDate, to = EndDate, auto.assign = FALSE)[,6], pos = 1)
}

# Retrieving price data from Yahoo Finance
for (i in seq_along(Tickers)) {
  SymLookup(Tickers[i],StartDate)
}
### At this point we have 5 newly created xts objects which all have variable
### names corresponding to the 5 character strings in the Tickers vector
### i.e. RY is now an xts object from 2001-01-01 to today etc.


### Attempting to systematically merge XTS dataframes together

BtBB <- assign(BtBB_syms, merge(BtBB_syms))
# Doesn't work - no default value for "y" which is missing

BtBB <- merge(eval(parse(text = Tickers)))
# This works, but only creates a merged data.frame with 
# the last instance of Tickers, CM 

BtBB <- merge(as.name(Tickers))
# Cannot coerce class `"name"` to a data.frame

BtBB <- merge(rlang::syms(Tickers))
# Same error as first attempt with assign function
```

I am hoping to just create a merged xts object with *n* number of columns created from however many symbols I input into the initial **Tickers** vector.

Basically I'm trying to reference variables in the global environment by using a vector of strings (*plural*) that I created previously.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Outside the loop, make a list to hold results `res <- list()`. Inside the loop, assign like `res[[ Tickers[i] ]] <- getSymbols(...)` and don't use `assign`. Then you can access results like `res[[ "RY" ]]` or combine `res` into one object as needed.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much! I love this website!!!

Comment: Also why are the solutions to my problems always so simple :S

Comment: Glad it helps :) In this case, I think everyone has run into this problem as they learn R. You might be interested in free e-book R Inferno or the fortunes package, which are funny and useful to build intuition. The typical fortunes reference for this one is `fortunes::fortune(236)`